# iOSでウェブブラウザのaudioタグからロック画面にアルバムアートワークを表示したい

Tags: ios, html, safari, web-audio

iOSの端末(iPhone等）で`<audio></audio>`を用いて音楽を再生するとき、
アルバムアートワークをロック画面に表示させるようにしたいです。

```
<audio title="タイトル" src="test.mp3" controls></audio>
```

上のコードのようにtitleを付加するとロック画面にタイトル名が表示されるのですが、
アルバムアートワークを表示させる方法が分かりませんでした。
album,artist,artworkURL,posterなどを試してみましたが表示されませんでした。

Safariのリファレンスのaudioの項目にはtitleについても書かれていませんでした。
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/HTMLTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001262-SW2

このようなことは可能でしょうか？
お力添えよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[title属性はグローバル属性なので](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title)あらゆる要素に適用できますが、その表示方法は要素によって、あるいはブラウザや環境によって異なります。その一環として、iPhoneのSafariでは楽曲名としてロック画面に表示しているのでしょう。

そして、現段階では[audio要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)に他のメタデータを指定する属性は用意されていません。

[Media Session Standard](https://wicg.github.io/mediasession/) として端末の再生コントロールと双方向に連携するAPIが検討されてはいますが、[現在サポートしているのは Chrome for Android ぐらい](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5639924124483584)のものです。

ちなみにWebKit(Safari)では、[昨年末のコミット](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/209240)にこんなことが書かれていました。

> I am not exactly sure of the status of this code. When I enabled it to test my
>   changes it did not compile until I fixed some things, and it's far out of date
>   of the latest draft of the Media Session Standard.